# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Core (and others)

Tags: arch-linux, gcc

I try to compile Simon Voice Recognition Software version 0.4.90 from source on Arch Linux with KDE Plasma.

Source was obtained using `git clone git://anongit.kde.org/simon simonsource`
When I execute `./build.sh` (or `make` in build directory, build just calls it), I get following error:

```
[ 70%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../lib/simonatspicommandplugin.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Widgets
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::DBus
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [plugins/Commands/ATSPI/CMakeFiles/simonatspicommandplugin.dir/build.make:144: lib/simonatspicommandplugin.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6429: plugins/Commands/ATSPI/CMakeFiles/simonatspicommandplugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

I installed whole `qt5` group from Arch repositories, also `cxxtools` from AUR, but to no avail.

linker version:

`GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.30`

gcc version:

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.1 20180531 (GCC)
```

Thank you

Comment: There is a [PKGBUILD in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/simon/), use that...

Comment: simon from AUR doesn't work, fails on syntax error

Comment: The maintainer is a competent developer, so either leave a note on the AUR page, or edit your question to include the syntax error.

Comment: The developer supposedly abandoned project year ago